# How to disable blue warning underline sign in flutter/dart extension?

Tags: visual-studio, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Can someone tell me how to disable the warning underlines in my code? I have posted the picture below. The blue wiggly signs are a pain while writing more codes.
I tried to disable the SDK Formatter from the extension settings but it didn't work for me.

[image: The blue lines pictured above]

Comment: what is the error displayed when you put the mouse hover it?

Comment: Mouseover to see why your IDE is complaining and then fix it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are missing `const` keyword there.

```
void main() => runApp(
      const MaterialApp(
        home: Text("hello"),
      ),
    );
```

Linting code is good practice. But it's totally up to you to lint the code. If you want to disable linting, remove this line in `pubspec.yaml`,

```
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0  // remove this line
```

and finally delete the `analysis_options.yaml` file in your project directory

Answer (score 1):

Try to Write this code

```
    void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Text('hello'),
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The underlines note problems regarding your code.

- red squiggles are representing syntax errors
- blue squiggles are representing compiler errors
- green squiggles are representing warnings

Now, your line is blue, so it is safe to assume that you do not want to see the location of compiler errors being underlined while you write code, at least in Visual Studio 2015, according to [this source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d83134c7-773f-4b87-913e-01de8240568a/visual-studio-2015-to-stop-underlining-errors-and-stuff?forum=visualstudiogeneral) you can do something like this:

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor ->  -> Advanced -> IntelliSense -> Disable Squiggles

Answer (score 0):

Step1: Go to the pubspec.yaml file

[image]

Step2: find `flutter_lints: ^1.0.0`   and remove it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Step1: Go to analysis_options.yaml

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQMXT.png

Step2: find include: package:flutter_lints/flutter.yaml and Comment like this #include: package:flutter_lints/flutter.yaml

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlG4t.png