# when developing an application on flutter, the reason for code highlighting is not clear

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

why the working code is highlighted
[image]

Comment: what do you mean highlight? did you mean the blue underline?

Comment: Refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69583780/6784846

Comment: @pmatatias yes!

Comment: The `new` keyword is used to create an instance of a class. However, Dart 2 makes the new keyword optional. You can omit it. you  an use `const` keyword instead to make that specific widget to not rebuild again when the build() method called.

Comment: the indent maybe not right, or is because of ```new```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the newest version of Flutter, the `new` keyword is not needed. Other reasons you could be getting this error:

- You need to put a `const` keyword in front of widgets whose data is constant. Example: `const EdgeInsets.all(20)` instead of just the `EdgeInsets.all(20)`.
- You need to sort the `child` property for widgets last. It can't be above any other property (don't think this is your problem).
- You need to add a `Key` to widgets (this appears to be your problem for the underline under `App`). [Check my answer here for what to do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73886342/13029516).

Comment: @Gybernaty if this answer helped you, don't forget to click the check box for it in order to accept it. This will help others who view it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It because your IDE is recommend you to using `const` on your `<widget>`.

Answer (score 0):

> why the working code is highlighted

Instead of us *guessing* what rules your project has enabled to bring up those warning, you could just hover over the highlighted section and your IDE should *tell you* what is is it thinks is not up to the rules of your project.

There should also be a list available in an extra window, though I have no idea what that window is called in Visual Studio Code.